не работает анимация в live2d модели
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема, запускаю проект и вижу что анимация которая выставлена напрямую не срабатывает, при этом работает анимация моргания глаз. Я новичок, и по большей части пользуюсь чатом GPT. Просто хочу посмотреть как работает live2d модели на вебе[ссылка на архив с проектом][1]
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CA42nyZnjbJJOI4OazmaiQikQ6jJ1MUm/view?usp=sharing
import { useEffect } from "react";
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";
const { Live2DModel } = require("pixi-live2d-display/lib/cubism4");

window.PIXI = PIXI;

Live2DModel.registerTicker(PIXI.Ticker);

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const app = new PIXI.Application({
      view: document.getElementById("canvas"),
      autoStart: true,
      resizeTo: window,
    });

    Live2DModel.from("/runtime/Aqua.model3.json").then((model) => {
      app.stage.addChild(model);

      model.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
      model.position.set(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
      model.scale.set(0.2, 0.2);

      model.motion("motions/00_Anger_01.motion3.json");
    });
  }, []);

  return <canvas id="canvas" />;
}

export default App;

